# node.js modules pass object to singleton

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a class being used in node.js, and I want to pass various objects to this when requiring it.

Here's the class:

```
    var ItemHandler = (function() {

          var items = new Array();

          return { 
            start: function (item, callback) {

                items.push(item);
                ItemHandler.timer();

            },
            timer: function () {

                var timer = setTimeout(function() {

                    console.log('test');
                    ItemHandler.timer();

                }, 1000);
            }
          };
        })();

module.exports = ItemHandler;
```

This is being called in one my routes, index.js.  Like this:

```
var itemHandler = require('./lib/item.handler.js');
itemHandler.start(items);
```

What I would like to do is pass other objects being used in my route, to this file.  Similar to this:

```
var itemHandler = require('./lib/item.handler.js')(socket)(res);
```

Here, I'd be passing in the socket object (returned from  a socket.io connection and a response).

How would I structure my class to accept those two parameters?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what does your ItemHandler class need those parameters for?  That could impact the solution greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ItemHandler(param) {
  var items = new Array();

  ItemHandler.start = function (item, callback) {
    items.push(item);
    ItemHandler.timer();
  };

  ItemHandler.timer = function () {
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('test');
      ItemHandler.timer();
    }, 1000);
  }

  return ItemHandler;
};

module.exports = ItemHandler;
```

`ItemHandler` is now a function so...

```
var itemHandler = require('./lib/item.handler.js')(socket)(res);
itemHandler.start(items);
```

Or:

```
var itemHandler = require('./lib/item.handler.js');
itemHandler(socket)(res).start(items);
```

Hope it works, haven't tested it :)

Comment: Thanks, haven't tested it yet, but this would remove the 'singleton' nature of the class right? Although, I think my implementation above also doesn't seem to really be a singleton, it letting the setTimeout pile up, the more times its run.

Comment: Yea I guess my aproach is not a singleton since you can call `new` and get a new object...but why would you do that :). Yours it is however (tehnically), but indeed the timers would pile up. You can tweak this easily...just init some bool the first time timer() it called.